# How to put a .js file in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsfiddle

The question seeems pretty simple.The usual method is simply using this code

```
<script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc9/angular-1.0.0rc9.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Alternatively, in Jsfiddle, we use the "External resources tab"

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](https://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/07/13/53c2f8f434f6a.png))</sub>

I have issues in implementing a particular code in my website. After much troubleshooting, I found out that, if I use this code to put a .js file:

```
 <script src='file link here' type='text/javascript'/>
```

the code doesn't work. If I use the external resources option in jsfiddle, it works. If I manually put it, it doesn't

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/1972/
Unworking fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/1973/

I am shocked as to how this is possible.

Comment: script tags aren't self-closing `<script src='file link here' type='text/javascript'></script>` http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/1974/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The end tag for script elements is [mandatory](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

```
<script 
    src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc9/angular-1.0.0rc9.js' 
    type='text/javascript'>
</script>
```

Comment: Haha, not a retard Michel....just one of many people who had yet to have made that particular mistake! Catches most people at one point or another.

Comment: Actually the empty tag would work in XHTML (although jsfiddle may not support XHTML). So it's not such an invalid way of inserting a script in HTML code...